# Why do strings from plist not display in correct order in a UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a plist in my app that contain rows in the Root Dictionary , when i add this rows in `NSMutableArray` by the following code:

```
NSString * item = [badgeDict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"item%i",indexPath.row+1]];
[badgeArray addObject:item];
```

It gives me scrambled sorted array... 
I wanted it to be in the same order... putting in mind that the key of those rows called (item1,item2,item3...,etc)...

How it should be fixed?

Comment: also you say the array is out of order, did you print out the actual contents of the array to verify that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will be scrambled since your code is in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

UITableViewCells are cached.  Since you didnt show the relevant surrounding code, its pretty likely that you are redisplaying cached cells.

Answer (score 2):

In tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: you can access the object in this manner

```
NSArray *keys = [[badgeDict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
id value = [badgeDict objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

This is good if your plist is small otherwise save keys order in your member variable.

Answer (score 1):

Take in account that `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` gets called whenever new cell is needed: when filling the `UITableView` for first time and whenever a cell appears when scrolling. So, it's not a good practice to populate your data source in this method.

I would suggest you to populate your data in the `viewDidLoad`. If the `UITableView` needs to refresh the information contained somehow, then create a method to do so and call it from `viewDidLoad` and from where refresh happens (for instance pressing a button, when pull to refresh,...).

Answer (score 1):

I sugest you to move this code to viewDidLoad method instead of cellForRowAtIndexPath, it might be that you call methods like reloadRowsAtIndexPaths and that will break the order if your badgeArray is instance variable, moreover you may not fully fill your entire array because not all rows are shown on the screen at once.

Your approach doesn't seem to be efficient. If your badgeDict is a subject to change you may try implementing notifications. Simply add your UIViewController as observer to badgeDict changes and reload badgeArray in case of such event.

To do so:

- in your viewController's viewDidLoad add:

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshBadgeArray:) name:@"BadgeChanged" object:nil];
- in your viewController's dealloc add:

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
- in place where badgeDict is changed:

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"BadgeChanged" object:self];